# Clicking on radiobutton returns undefined values

Tags: reactjs

I want to create an app where you can choose quantity fo water that you have drinked. I want to use radiobuttons in form for 3 default values -250ml, 500ml and 1000ml. 
I created radiobuttons, but when I click on them, I get undefined value after e.target method.

I tried to bind my functions on checked and onChange but it didn't help.

Main component WaterApp.js:

```
import WaterButtons from './WaterButtons';

const quantitiesData = [
    {
        id: 'water_250_ml',
        value: 250,
        name: 'water_250_ml'
    },
    {
        id: 'water_500_ml',
        value: 500,
        name: 'water_500_ml'
    },
    {
        id: 'water_1000_ml',
        value: 1000,
        name: 'water_1000_ml'
    }
];

export default class WaterApp extends React.Component {
    state = {
        waterQuantity: 'water_250_ml'
    };

    handleCheckedWaterQuantity = (e) => {
        this.state.checkedQuantity === e.target.value;
    }

    handleWaterQuantityChange = (e) => {
        const waterQuantity = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ waterQuantity });
        console.log(waterQuantity);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form>
                    <WaterButtons
                        quantities={quantitiesData}
                        handleCheckedWaterQuantity={(e) => this.handleCheckedWaterQuantity(e)}
                        handleWaterQuantityChange={(e) => this.handleWaterQuantityChange(e)}
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

WaterButtons.js

```
import WaterButton from './WaterButton';

const WaterButtons = (props) => (
    <div>
        {
            props.quantities.map((quantity) => (
                <WaterButton
                    key={quantity.id}
                    id={quantity.id}
                    value={quantity.value}
                    label={quantity.name}
                    checked={props.handleCheckedWaterQuantity}
                    handleWaterQuantityChange={props.handleWaterQuantityChange}
                />
            ))
        }
    </div>
);

export default WaterButtons;
```

WaterButton.js

```
const WaterButton = (props) => (
    <div>
        <input
            type="radio"
            id={props.id}
            value={props.value}
            name="waterQuantity"
            checked={props.checked}
            onChange={(e) => {props.handleWaterQuantityChange(props.value)}}
        />
        <label htmlFor={props.id}>
            {props.label}
        </label>
    </div>
);

export default WaterButton;
```

I want to get the value for clicked radiobutton.

[EDIT] Also, I have a problem with checked value for every radiobutton. Function that is now is not working. I thought maybe I should change my code so that in WaterButton.js i define state for buttons. Then it would have to be class not stateless component.

Comment: Have you tried using `e.currentTarget.value` rather than e.target.value? "[currentTarget] always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to Event.target, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its direct descendant."  [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling handleWaterQuantityChange with incorrect argument please see the below code

Your onChange should be `onChange={(e) => {props.handleWaterQuantityChange(e)}}`

```
const WaterButton = (props) => (
    <div>
        <input
            type="radio"
            id={props.id}
            value={props.value}
            name="waterQuantity"
            checked={props.checked}
            onChange={(e) => {props.handleWaterQuantityChange(e)}}
        />
        <label htmlFor={props.id}>
            {props.label}
        </label>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In props.handleWaterQuantityChange you are passing props.value instead of event

```
<input
            type="radio"
            id={props.id}
            value={props.value}
            name="waterQuantity"
            checked={props.checked}
            onChange={(e) => {props.handleWaterQuantityChange(e)}}
```

or

```
<input
            type="radio"
            id={props.id}
            value={props.value}
            name="waterQuantity"
            checked={props.checked}
            onChange={props.handleWaterQuantityChange}
```